# Selectively suppress custom Obsolete warnings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I'm using the `Obsolete` attribute (as just suggested by fellow programmers) to show a warning if a certain method is used.

Is there a way to suppress the warning similar to CodeAnalysis' `SuppressMessage` at points where the use is justified?

This needs to work for `[Obsolete("Some message")]` which generates warning 618 and the plain `[Obsolete]` attribute with no message which generates warning 612.

Comment: In generated code, it looks like a tough one. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66653324/2157640

Comment: In the link above, I posted an answer that works since VS 2019. I am hesitant to repost the relevant part here as this Q is tagged [tag:visual-studio-2008]. TL;DR is: If there is a file name pattern where you need to suppress the warnings, use EditorConfig.

Answer (score 292, accepted):

Use `#pragma warning disable`:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    [Obsolete("Message")]
    static void Foo(string x)
    {
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
#pragma warning disable 0618
        // This one is okay
        Foo("Good");
#pragma warning restore 0618

        // This call is bad
        Foo("Bad");
    }
}
```

Restore the warning afterwards so that you won't miss "bad" calls.

Comment: This only works if I don't give a message with my Obsolete attribute. I have a message though like this: [Obsolete("This is why this shouldnt be used - use XYZ instead.")]. Once I put the message in, the pragma warning disable 612 stops working and I'm getting warnings regardless. Do I need another error ID instead maybe?

Comment: Found it - The correct warning number is 618 if there's a message in the Obsolete attribute. Thank you!

Comment: Goodo - I've adjusted my example to match this.

Comment: Is there some place where the warning numbers are listed?

Comment: @George: You can find them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228296.aspx).

Comment: See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968293/c-sharp-selectively-suppress-custom-obsolete-warnings#9751124) on how to get the warning/error number in the first place.

Comment: What if you use the Error=true parameter in the Obsolete attribute? Can you still prevent the compiler error. I would like to clearly express that the method is not to be used, but I don't want to delete all my unit tests (yet) until the new test methods have similar tolerance/variety coverage. Using internalsvisibleto is possible, but more impactful on the code than just putting an obsolete attribute and pragma in the test project. I don't like test induced damage.

Comment: @Tormod: No, I don't believe you can ignore an obsolete-with-error attribute. You could potentially use conditional compilation - introduce a new build configuration that doesn't have them as errors, and only run the unit tests there. Or (ugly) use reflection...

Comment: Could you update the code to disable for 0612 as well please in case some readers use plain `[Obsolete]` without a message.

Comment: @Jordão Note also that Visual Studio editor automatically unindents `#pragma` directives.

Comment: Earlier you had `0612`, but then it was changed to `0618` for `Obsolete` tags that had custom messages associated.  For vanilla `Obsolete` tags though, it looks like you still need `0612`.  Perhaps this answer can show examples of both and explain the difference.

Comment: @Panzercrisis: I'll see if I can find time to do that at some point. Not right now though.

Answer (score 151):

The *intent* is to disable the warning for obsolete *usage*, regardless of whether the construct is marked with `[Obsolete]` or `[Obsolete("Message")]`. So use both [CS0612](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0h063ka.aspx) *and* [CS0618](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5ye6x1e.aspx):

```
#pragma warning disable 612, 618 

...

#pragma warning restore 612, 618
```

Comment: Also note that the warnings don't occur if the obsolete usage is in a class that is itself marked as obsolete.

Comment: Is there a way to disable an error as well, in case `Obsolete` was marked as an error?

Comment: @Shimmy: if it's marked as an error, then you must fix it, there's no way to suppress errors. It might be a syntax problem, post it as a question on this site, and you'll certainly get a good answer.

Answer (score 21):

Here's **how to get the warning/error number** in the first place:

1. *Rebuild* your project.
2. Go to the *[Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hk6fby3.aspx)* window.
3. Look up the line of the warning/error you want to suppress.
   For example:
   `C:\Users\Username\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Projectname\Classname.cs(203,7): warning CS`**`0162`**`: Unreachable code detected`
4. Copy the number part **after** "`CS`".
5. Then proceed as Jon Skeet [says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968293/c-sharp-selectively-suppress-custom-obsolete-warnings#968311).

<sub>(Better *always* proceed as [Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9134/164541) says…)</sub>

Answer (score 9):

You're looking for the `#pragma` warning disable directive

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys(VS.80).aspx

Essentially you add the following command above the call site in the .cs file.

```
#pragma warning disable 612
SomeMethodCall
```

612 is the error message ID for calling obsolete methods

Comment: This only works if I don't give a message with my Obsolete attribute. I have a message though like this: [Obsolete("This is why this shouldnt be used - use XYZ instead.")]. Once I put the message in, the pragma warning disable 612 stops working and I'm getting warnings regardless. Do I need another error ID instead maybe?

Comment: Found it - The correct warning number is 618 if there's a message in the Obsolete attribute.