# How to ignore compiler warning when using Obsolete attribute on a class used with a KnownType attribute

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, compiler-warnings

So we are trying to deprecate some of our existing classes, and have started marking them as obsolete with the ObsoleteAttribute so they will stop being used.  The fact that using the KnownType attribute with a type that is marked with the Obsolete attribute and is causing a compiler warning is expected.  However, in our project we have warnings treated as errors so ignoring the warning isn't an option. Is there a compiler directive to suppress this warning?

The following usage causes a compiler warning:

```
///ProductTemplateDataSet is marked with the Obsolete attribute
[KnownType(typeof(ProductTemplateDataSet))]
public class EntityCollectionBase : System.Data.DataSet
{
}
```

Edit:  I understand using compiler directives to ignore errors, but this compiler warning doesn't have a number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Selectively suppress custom Obsolete warnings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968293/c-sharp-selectively-suppress-custom-obsolete-warnings)

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Use this to disable the corresponding warnings just before the offending line:

```
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
```

And reenable the warnings after it:

```
#pragma warning restore 612, 618
```

Curiously enough, there're 2 warnings related to this: [CS0612](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0h063ka.aspx) and [CS0618](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5ye6x1e.aspx) - one is for `[Obsolete]` and the other for `[Obsolete("Message")]`. Go figure...

Comment: If you'd like to avoid adding `#pragma`s to your code, you can have a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 69):

If you want to avoid having to pepper your code with `#prgrama`s, try this:
In your csproj file, find the appropriate `PropertyGroup` element and add

```
<WarningsNotAsErrors>612,618</WarningsNotAsErrors>
```

here's a snippet from one of my project files:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <WarningsNotAsErrors>612,618</WarningsNotAsErrors>
    <NoWarn>
    </NoWarn>
    <WarningsAsErrors>
    </WarningsAsErrors>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I've used this successfully with VS2010, VS2012, and VS2013 projects.

Comment: Actually, the `<NoWarn />` block is where  you want to put it.  Specifying this information in the `<WarningsNotAsErrors />` block will just demote the errors back to regular warnings (you have `<TreatWarningsAsErrors />` set to true).

Comment: I don't think hiding the warning is the intention of the OP.  After all, they are are deliberately adding the `Obsolete` attribute to their own code.  The problem is that they also have **treat Warnings as Errors** enabled which prevents them from building their project.  The solution I laid out allows them to preserve the `Obsolete` warning *and* build their project.

Comment: additionally add these warning to 'Suppress warnings'-box in project settings (Project -> Properties -> Build) to hide them from warnings-list

Comment: @vladimir77, again, the point wasn't to suppress the warnings.  It was to keep them as warnings while treating all other warnings as errors.

Comment: Not sure why this isn't "the" answer. The warnings (especially for obsolete which are liable to disappear from ABI at some point) should generally stay until resolved; the compilation failures should not.

Comment: @MetaFight if we don't want to use <WarningNotAsErrors> block is there any fix to this ?

Answer (score 5):

Could you just use a `#pragma` listing the appropriate warning number?

[#pragma warning (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

**EDIT**

Found this but it's a bit late [C# - Selectively suppress custom Obsolete warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968293/c-selectively-suppress-custom-obsolete-warnings)

Comment: Right, but what warning number?  It doesn't say from the compiler output.

Comment: You could go nuclear on it; "When no warning numbers are specified, disable disables all warnings and restore enables all warnings."

Comment: "Warning as Error: 'classblah' is obsolete 'D:\Development\blah.cs'" line number 14 and column 12.