# Set suppress warnings for website

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I am working with a project from another developer that has hundreds of obsolete method warnings. In the compiled dlls, I set suppress warnings 618 (the full warning number is [CS0618](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5ye6x1e%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)).

Is there a way to set the same setting on a web site?

The problem is that there are so many obsolete warnings that I can't find any of the important ones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you need to specify this in the web.config. See also: [Compiler Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9x69bzw.aspx) and [Web Project Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fdbs127%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp"
        extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, 
          Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, 
          PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
        compilerOptions="/nowarn:618"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

An alternative would be to [add `#pragma` statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275072/how-to-ignore-compiler-warning-when-using-obsolete-attribute-on-a-class-used-with) around each of the offending methods, but if there are hundreds, the blanket suppression would probably be quicker.

```
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
[Obsolete("Use something else instead")]
#pragma warning restore 612, 618
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct that adding `#pragma` around each statement is not an option. I used the web.config option and I went from 311 warnings to 2 (which are easy enough to fix.)

Comment: If I have a .net 4.6.2 project and my Microsoft.CSharp reference is for .net 4.0, is it better that I specify its Version instead of the 2.0.3600.0 you have here?