# Suppress build warnings for generated code behind of Web Site Visual Studio project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, msbuild, vs-web-site-project

Is there a way to suppress specific build warnings for generated code behind of [Web Site Visual Studio project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Because the project is a `Web Site` type project (has no project file) it is not possible to globally suppress the warnings for it under `Properties` -> `Build` -> `Suppress Warnings`.

And since the ASPX file is being dynamically generated/compiled, using `#pragma warning disable` is not possible at all.

---

Working solution following lurker's help:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp"
          extension=".cs"
          type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
          warningLevel="4"
          compilerOptions="/nowarn:108,109">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0"/>
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
      </compiler>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a  section in the web.config file where options to suppressing warnings are set.  See the answer here: [Set suppress warnings for website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067939/set-suppress-warnings-for-website).  There are also links to pages which have the specific values.