# Why Obsolete causes error?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I use:

```
[Obsolete("Use AnotherMethod() insted.", false)]
```

2nd parameter is `false` but Visual Studio shows Warning as Error for every obsolete method call preventing project from compilation. How to make VS mark these calls as Warning not Error?

Comment: Check this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520853/warning-as-error-how-to-rid-these][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520853/warning-as-error-how-to-rid-these

Comment: Not a solution of my problem. In that answer is suggested to disable warnings at all but I need to disable only for `Obsolete`.

Comment: Then simply said: there is no solution. Obsolete warning, warning as error -> vs blows with error. Simple logic for beginners.

Comment: Did you tiry this solution?
[Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275072/how-to-ignore-compiler-warning-when-using-obsolete-attribute-on-a-class-used-wit

Comment: @DotNETNinja Check this out ,suits you better in my case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968293/c-sharp-selectively-suppress-custom-obsolete-warnings

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the obsolete method define:

```
#pragma warning disable 0618
        [Obsolete("test",false)]
        private void myMethod()
```

then go to project properties, under build, in suppress warning type type 0618, Now it will ignore that particular method and project will compile

Comment: marking in project file was enough. but I had to do it into `csproj` directly