# What is the difference between warning codes cs0618 and cs0612

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, error-code

I have seen both of the following warning codes being thrown for utilization of code marked obsolete.

[cs0618](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5ye6x1e.aspx) and [cs0612](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0h063ka%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

0618 is Level 2 and 0612 is level 1 according to the documentation.  Does anyone know what the difference is between these codes is and what causes one to be thrown instead of the other?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the difference is that one contains a message and the other doesn't.

```
[Obsolete]                                  // CS0612
[Obsolete("Use newMethod instead", false)]  // CS0618
[Obsolete("Use newMethod instead", true)]   // CS0619
```

Comment: I got the same results -- in addition, if you pass "true" to the Obsolete attribute, to make it an error, you get a CS0619

Comment: @JMarsch: +1 Good spot, added to answer.

Comment: Let's explain it with more words:

- if you add a message, then you'll get a CS0618.

- you can additionally set the IsError property of the Obsolete attribute to true, and thus an exception will be thrown if the item is referenced. That results in CS0619