# Adding extended logic to a migration

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm trying to manage complex data model changes through migrations, but I'm not sure this is the best approach.

In this example, I have a `Customer` entity that has these properties:

```
public string Address { get; set; }
public string PostalOrZip { get; set; }
public string ProvinceOrState { get; set; }
```

Now, I want to create a new entity called `CustomerAddress` which holds the same 3 properties, but would allow the model to hold many addresses for a `Customer`

I have done so and created a migration as follow

```
public partial class customeraddress_table : Migration
{
    
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "CustomerAddress",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                CustomerId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                Address = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                PostalOrZip = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                ProvinceOrState = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                CreatedOn = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
                ModifiedOn = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_CustomerAddress", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_CustomerAddress_Customer_CustomerId",
                    column: x => x.CustomerId,
                    principalTable: "Customer",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_CustomerAddress_CustomerId",
            table: "CustomerAddress",
            column: "CustomerId");


        
      
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "CustomerAddress");
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do in that migration, is iterate through all the `Customers` and create a `CustomerAddress` for each of them, and copy the address info from `Customer`.

I've tought of using `migrationBuilder.Sql` but using the context would be great because I have useful logic in `SaveChangesAsync` that I would need to replicate in the SQL.

Can migrations handle such a requirement ? Is there a better approach than migrations then ?

Comment: What you can do is add your own custom code after the generated one or even better generate a new blank migration file and in UP method specify `migrationBuilder.Sql(@"wrtie SQL here to move data...")` where you'd do the data manipulation you like

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

You *absolutely **should*** be using `.Sql` to perform this type of data manipulation. During a migration the `DbContext` cannot be used because the database schema does not yet conform to the model expectation, that is the point of the migration, to prepare the database so that the current version of the `DbContext` can work at all.

Importantly, the migration logic can and needs to be exectued without any dependency on your model, this is important if you consider the extreme case of starting your app with an entirely new database in the connection string, without custom management of the migrations, all of the migrations before *NOW* will and **must** be executed in sequence before your application will run. If you tried to execute code from last year against your current `DbContext` I'm betting it wouldn't compile, let alone execute successfully.

> Similar issues arise if you have need of rolling back migrations...

Yes it is a little bit annoying to have to manually perform some of the auto-manipulations that we have built into the context, but here is the important part:

## During Schema manipulations our automatic or trigger logic almost *NEVER* applies!

"What, you can't be serious" I hear you say? Think about it, if your auto-logic is setting the timestamps for audit fields like *created* and *modified* and setting them to `DateTime.Now` (or something similar) then those values would be incorrect for this data that we are migrating across, in this instance for a true Audit Record, we should be copying across the timestamps and users from the original `Customer` record.

*If you really did need the auto-logic to run **ALL** the time, even on schema manipulation then perhaps it is a candidate for a DB Trigger, yes you can do these even with EF Code First, it takes a lot of setup to automate, but you could set this up in `migrationBuilder.Sql()`*

> ...using the context would be great because I have useful logic in SaveChangesAsync that I would need to replicate in the SQL.

### Please do not try this at home...

If you want to use any `DbContext` then you need to execute this as part of your *Seed* logic that runs *after* a migration. Which means you would have to code your migration over two steps:

1. Migration 1: Create the new Schema elements

   - In *Seed* insert the necessary records into the new tables
2. `pm> Update-Database`
3. Migration 2: Remove the old Schema elements

   - Remove the previous code in the *Seed* logic, because now the schema elements have been removed from the model.
4. `pm> Update-Database`

***DO NOT* go there!** Although this will work in your development box, and maybe you do not have more than 1 single deployment, or you are actively developing on your production environment database... Whatever justification you think you have, it is not a valid one.

This is an absolute RED FLAG to do as a one shot in isolation, the above steps are not repeatable on a separate database schema at any other point in time, so unless you are going to simultaneously execute this migration on all of your database instances at the same time before you remove the elements from the schema, it simply will not work and:

***it is not a good habit to get into the practise of, this is a band-aide solution at best***

---

## Deprecation

There is a standard Software Engineering solution for this when you have a significant schema change that involves removing tables or fields from the schema that are critical but you need to run complex logic using your `DbContext` or your solution is distributed in a way that there are lots of dependencies that need to react to the change, but they can only do so after the new schema elements have been made available.

This follows the same principals as the hacky approach above, but over a much longer amount of time, and potentially many version releases.

> This occurs commonly in Micro-Service architecture or API based solutions where deployments must not interferer with 3 or 4 9s SLAs. In this case the old code (the previous `DbContext`) needs to still be able to utilise the database as the new Context code is being rolled out to each server instance in your farm.

Adding new elements is usually backwards compatible, any non-breaking changes can be applied whenever you need to.

To apply breaking changes, sometimes we are forced to first mark those classes, methods or properties first as `[Obsolete]`. Then in all of the code that you have access to or control over, you can remove references or replace them as you need to.

For example, an EF backed OData API that has client apps that use the Connected Serices (Client Side Proxies) the following sequence should be employed to safely roll out changes to a high SLA production environment, lets say deployed to MS Azure.

0. Disable automatic migrations, or configure your Migration Strategy to forward only.
1. Data Context:

   - Add new Tables the schema,
   - mark old ones as obsolete (if you are removing any)

     - make fields to remove *NULLABLE* if they were not already
   - `PM> Add-Migration "Customer Addresses"`
   - Edit the migration script, include `Sql()` logic to insert the records and null out or remove the old ones
   - Follow the [deprecation warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10359146/1690217) (CS0612,CS0618,CS0619) to make the necessary code changes so your data context and related code is ready for that later steps.

1.5. It is generally SAFE to `PM> Update-Database` at this point in time.

- So you can test and deploy having only gone this far, allowing the rest of your team to react to the deprecation warnings.

2. API - regenerate or manipulate your *EdmModel* and API Controllers to include the new elements, you cannot yet remove the old elements, if you are using automation techniques that exclude references to `Obsolete` members, you may have to disable these features or otherwise manually re-instate the previous schema elements.

   - These elements need to remain or we will break validation performed in the ODataClient logic on the clients.
   - It is a good idea to add specific logic to re-route or at least handle any requests that try to manipulate the obsolete fields, to reduce the impact of schema changes later

     For instance, On Customer PATCH, if the `Address` is modified, you would also update the associated/default/top 1 record in the new `Addresses` table.
3. Test Deploy and Test again your API end to end, you should not have introduced any changes that break clients, not yet... if you have, rollback the API deployment.
4. Notify client developers that the API has changed, describe the new schema elements, with advice on how to manage the changes and declare the elements that will be removed in *a future version* and that they should prepare their client-side models to operate without these elements.
5. We give clients enough time, which might be a number of years to regenerate their client-side proxies and update their logic, because everyone reads the documentation, we can assume they have also made the neccessary preparations to remove references to the deprecated schema elements.

... continue rolling out non-breaking changes and improvements to your schema and APIs

6. At some point you decide it is time, so now you can remove the elements from your EF model

   - `PM> Add-Migration "Customer Remove Address Fields PREPARATION"`
   - Edit the migration script to **COMMENT OUT** *do not remove* **STEPS THAT DROP SCHEMA ELEMENTS!**

     - ***!!! Super important !!!*** - The old SQL needs to be valid so the previous versions of the API will still execute, but we need EF to "think" that the model changes have been applied to the database.
       We comment out the generated logic, because we might want to refer to it later when it comes time finish cleaning up the schema.
   - `PM> Update-Database` is generally safe, this time because it should not have any changes in it, or at-least because you removed all the breaking ones.
7. Regenerate or code your EdmModel and API Controllers. This should remove the properties that were previously referenced.
8. Deploy the API, notify client developers again, this time noting the breaking changes...

   - We already told them this was coming, so no one should complain, you could rollback the API deployment or leave some old versions up at a different URL or versioned route if you need to
9. Client developers can do the client proxy process again in their own time.
10. Once you have confirmed that no clients are using the old code, or routes and verified that no instances of the previous API controller logic are in operation anywhere, *then* we can finish the cleanup process...

- `PM> Add-Migration Customer Remove Address Fields COMPLETION"
- This time, we need to run the logic to migrate or update the new Address records again, because the old clients may have updated the Obsolete fields.
- The Migration logic to remove the schema elements won't be in the migration script, as far as EF is concerned, they've already been removed, but back in *step 6* because we commented out the breaking changes, you can copy those migration operations into this migration step and of course uncomment them.

  Otherwise you will have to manually and carefully implement the change logic yourself to remove what you want from the schema.

11. `PM> Update-Database`
12. Republish your API, so that the new context is everywhere
13. Time for a drink!
    *I strongly advise many drinks at the end of each step, this is pplaying the long game. May I now also draw your attention to the [Ballmer Peak](https://xkcd.com/323/)*

Answer (score 0):

I would create an Address class that holds your three properties.

Then you can store a List in your CustomerAddress class using a One-to-Many relationship. You can then commit this as a new migration.

Then you can write a function that will go through the existing table of Customer object to populate your new tables/models.

The function would take each Customer object, create an Address object using the properties and add that address to the list in a new CustomerAddress object.

Afterwards, you can simply drop the Customer Table if you want

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following code at the end of the migration

```
//Copy the address info from the Customer object into a new CustomerAddress
migrationBuilder.Sql(@"INSERT INTO CustomerAddress
    SELECT Id as CustomerId, [Address], PostalOrZip, ProvinceOrState, GETDATE() as 
    CreatedOn, GETDATE() as ModifiedOn
    FROM Customer");
```

This works well, but usually, some logic in my context's `SaveChangesAsync()` populates the date fields, which I had to do here in the SQL code. This is why I'd like to use the context instead of direct SQL.