# SqlDbType.Time overflow. Value is out of range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I want to store time in a table and I take `time(7)` as datatype for storing the time. When I subtract two `DateTime`s, I got `"1.18:36:36.7484253"` as result in my `TimeSpan` variable. But the problem is that when I insert this value in my table, I got this error:

> **`SqlDbType.Time` overflow.** Value `'1.18:36:36.7484253'` is out of range. Must be between `00:00:00.0000000` and `23:59:59.9999999`.

I knew about this error and my question is what datatype I can use for this. I am using SQL Server 2008 and C#.

Comment: One simple option would be to store the number of ticks, milliseconds, seconds or whatever unit of granularity you want, just as an integer.

Comment: @JonSkeet how to use ticks.

Comment: You use the `TimeSpan.Ticks` property...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing TimeSpan with Entity Framework Codefirst - SqlDbType.Time overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129795/storing-timespan-with-entity-framework-codefirst-sqldbtype-time-overflow)

Answer (score 6):

SQL Server stores the time without days. The valid range should be between `00:00:00.0000000` and `23:59:59.9999999` as in the message.

For save days, you can convert `TimeSpan` to `Long` to method `Ticks` or sum the minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 0):

to resolve that problem, you need to do the following:

HI, you need to create a new TimeSpan Variable.

```
//////// Calculation for TimeStamp //////////

                DateTime fechaAux       = DateTime.Now;
                DateTime fechaIngresoAM = new DateTime(fechaAux.Year, fechaAux.Month, fechaAux.Day,  8, 30, 00);


                TimeSpan auxIngresoAM   = ingresoAM.Subtract(fechaIngresoAM);
                TimeSpan resultadoRetrasoIngresoAM = new TimeSpan(auxIngresoAM.Hours, auxIngresoAM.Minutes, auxIngresoAM.Milliseconds);



                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@retraso_ingreso_am", SqlDbType.Time));
                command.Parameters["@retraso_ingreso_am"].Value = resultadoRetrasoIngresoAM;

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It will work as you expect.

Comment: "It will work as you expect." No, it really won't. The OP is working with a timespan ~42 hours long. The SQL Server `time` data type is designed to hold a *time of day*, not a *time span*. As such, it doesn't support any values larger than 24 hours (nor does it support negatives, nor addition, etc, that you would also expect a time span data type to support)