# Prevent ObsoleteAttribute warning bubbling up call stack

Tags: c#, visual-studio, warnings, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I have a class using a deprecated assembly (`System.Data.OracleClient`). At compile time this results in a message `'MethodName()' is obsolete: 'OracleConnection has been deprecated.`
We can't replace this assembly and we are now trying to remove all warnings generated at compile time so that new warnings are clear to us.

It looks like whenever I try to suppress the warning using `[System.ObsoleteAttribute("OracleConnection has been deprecated. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=144260", false)]` the warning just gets pushed up the stack to the calling method.

In the example class below only method `E()` is using the deprecated assembly but I get a warning in method `A()` as it is the highest method in the stack without an `ObsoleteAttribute`. If I remove the attribute from `C()` then the warning gets pushed down the stack to `C()`.

```
public class OracleCaller
{
    public void A()
    {
        C();
    }
    [System.ObsoleteAttribute("OracleConnection has been deprecated. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=144260", false)]
    private void C()
    {
        D();
    }

    [System.ObsoleteAttribute("OracleConnection has been deprecated. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=144260", false)]
    private void D()
    {
        E();
    }
    [System.ObsoleteAttribute("OracleConnection has been deprecated. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=144260", false)]
    private void E()
    {
        System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand c = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand();
    }
}
```

In my application this will lead me to have to decorate methods with this attribute all the way up to the UI which seems pointless.

Can I get round this so that I only suppress the warning in the method where the assembly is called?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I get round this so that I only suppress the warning in the method where the assembly is called?

Yes - by using the normal way of suppressing warnings in C# - using `#pragma warning disable`.

Here's an example:

```
using System;

public class Test
{    
    static void Main()
    {
#pragma warning disable 0618       
        ObsoleteMethod();
#pragma warning restore 0618        
    }

    [Obsolete("Don't call me")]
    static void ObsoleteMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to use "0618" instead of "CS0612" though, thanks to another of your answers (http://stackoverflow.com/a/968311/1412915)

Comment: @Badgerspot: Interesting - looks like it depends on whether there's a message. Will edit.

Comment: I didn't even know `CS0618` would *ever work*; I always just use `0618`

Comment: @MarcGravell: It's possible that's a C# 6-ism (I know there are changes there, I believe to support code diagnostics). Will edit to just 0618 for backward compatibility :)