# Compiler Warning (level 2) CS0618 how to fix this

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin forms project, It gives me this kind of obsolete warning how to fix this

here my code

```
         public class CustomWebView : WebView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty =

        BindableProperty.Create<CustomWebView, string>(p => p.Uri, default(string));

    public string Uri
    {
        get => (string) GetValue(UriProperty);
        set => SetValue(UriProperty, value);
    }
}
```

how to fix this

Comment: Could you give us the entirety of the warning

Comment: And at which line the warning is?

Comment: [CS0618](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0618) appears to be warning you about using an `[Obsolete]` member. The text accompanying the warning should be very specific about which property

Comment: it's not a warning entirely its more ReSharper suggestion  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0618

Comment: To fix it: Use the newer version of the API. But since you haven't told us which API is obsolete, we cannot help.

Comment: #pragma warning disables @Jon Skeet already given an answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968293/c-sharp-selectively-suppress-custom-obsolete-warnings#968311

Comment: @SunilDhappadhule That's a bad idea in this situation, the real solution is to new the correct API.

Comment: there is no API it's just simple custom rendering part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for the [`BindableProperty.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableproperty.create) method show that the [generic version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableproperty.create?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_BindableProperty_Create__2_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1_____1_Xamarin_Forms_BindingMode_Xamarin_Forms_BindableProperty_ValidateValueDelegate___1__Xamarin_Forms_BindableProperty_BindingPropertyChangedDelegate___1__Xamarin_Forms_BindableProperty_BindingPropertyChangingDelegate___1__Xamarin_Forms_BindableProperty_CoerceValueDelegate___1__Xamarin_Forms_BindableProperty_CreateDefaultValueDelegate___0___1__) of this method has been *deprecated* since version 2.1.0 meaning you shouldn't be using it. Instead you should use the [non-generic overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableproperty.create?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_BindableProperty_Create_System_String_System_Type_System_Type_System_Object_Xamarin_Forms_BindingMode_Xamarin_Forms_BindableProperty_ValidateValueDelegate_Xamarin_Forms_BindableProperty_BindingPropertyChangedDelegate_Xamarin_Forms_BindableProperty_BindingPropertyChangingDelegate_Xamarin_Forms_BindableProperty_CoerceValueDelegate_Xamarin_Forms_BindableProperty_CreateDefaultValueDelegate_), so your code should look like this:

```
BindableProperty.Create("Uri", typeof(string), typeof(CustomWebView), default(string));
```